# visual studio code go user_settings go build flags

Tags: visual-studio-code

in visual studio code user_settings:

"go.buildFlags": ["-gcflags=\"-N -l\""],

vs code version:1.21.1
in the past releases，vscode could debug，but after upgrading, debug wrong because of compile optimization, add flags like above could not work, 
have a question:
invalid value "\"-N -l\"" for flag -gcflags: missing = in =
usage: build [-o output] [-i] [build flags] [packages]
Run 'go help build' for details.

ask for help
thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49641302/vscode-debug-issues-with-delve fix it as above