# vscode debug issues with Delve

Tags: visual-studio-code, delve

When I am debugging Go Lang code in visual studio code the below error message occured:

```
2018/04/03 18:19:32 server.go:73: Using API v1
2018/04/03 18:19:32 debugger.go:98: launching process with args: [$GOPATH/src/about/debug]
could not launch process: EOF
Process exiting with code: 1
```

Comment: Have the same issue, downgrading Xcode command line tools seem to solve it as here https://github.com/derekparker/delve/issues/1015 But I'm not sure that I want to go down this road.

Answer (score 3):

I tried below scenario and It worked..

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

then go to page https://developer.apple.com/download/more/
download and install previous version

Command Line Tools (macOS 10.13) for Xcode 9.1 - Dec 6, 2017
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thing. The latest XCode update breaks something in the debugger api. (I suspect it's just a change in `debugserver`'s command-line-flags.)

For now, the best solution I know of is to uninstall XCode or XCode Command Line tools and install Command Line Tools 9.2 for [MacOS High Sierra](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.2/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.2.dmg) or for [MacOs Sierra](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_9.2/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_9.2.dmg).

Install, and don't upgrade XCode until there's a fix, either in XCode or Delve.